# Passing values across two php files and loading data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to solve an existing problem - I have two files a. php and b. php and I am passing one value using HTTP get to b. php. Inside b. php I have following JavaScript code to get the HTTP get value. And by using the following code I am able to get the value. Then, I am trying to call a js function with this value and show data accordingly. But I am not getting any data, I assume it's for the URL.

How can I achieve that? Thanks!

post data from a.php (search=test)
b.php?search=test

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $_GET = {};
    if(document.location.toString().indexOf('?') !== -1) {
        var query = document.location
                       .toString()
                       .replace(/^.*?\?/, '')
                       .replace(/#.*$/, '')
                       .split('&');
        for(var i=0, l=query.length; i<l; i++) {
           var aux = decodeURIComponent(query[i]).split('=');
           $_GET[aux[0]] = aux[1];
        }
         callA("category",$_GET['search']);
    }    
});
```

```html
<?php echo '<form action="../b?search=<?php $search_all ?>" method="get" style="display:inline;">';?>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="Search by film, director or keyword"  onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search by film, director or keyword') {this.value = '';}" />
                        <input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

Comment: "And by using the following code I am able to get the value."
How do you know, that you got the value? How did you verify that?
Also, what does the code you use to send the value in a.php look like?

Comment: alert($_GET['search']); // to print the value

Comment: What do you need php for in this example? BTW: In javascript you can get the query string with location.search

Comment: <?php echo '<form action="../catalogue-test?search=<?php $search_all ?>" method="get" style="display:inline;">';?>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="Search by film, director or keyword"  onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search by film, director or keyword') {this.value = '';}" />
                        <input type="submit"  />
</form>

Comment: Please put the code in your original post and not into the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data from url on your javascript by just using the php command in it. see sample code below:

```js
<script>
  var search = '<?php echo $_GET['search'] ?>';
  alert(search);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! by using my code I am able to get the data but I want to call a js function using that data and show the results.